# SQL Query Criteria Syntax

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a question on a select query that I'm running within a MS Access database that's comparing two tables. 
My query returns blanks if I type in the criteria section:

```
Like "*[Name of field]*"
```

However I get the expected results if I type the below instead:

```
Like "*" & [Name of field] & "*"
```

Can anyone explain me the difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"*[name of field]*"`  gets interpreted exactly as written, where as `"*" & [name of field] & "*"` interprets the field, takes its value, and concatenates the leading and trailing `*`.  So if the value of [name of field] is "something", then

`"*[name of field]*"` --> `"*[name of field]*"`

`"*" & [name of field] & "*"` --> `"*something*"`